# MS 365 Access Form Dlookup #Name?

Tags: ms-access

Working with MS Access for the first time and coming across a few problems if someone could please help me
I have 3 tables and 1 form：

```
Table Plant {PID(key), Name}；  
Table Contractor {CID(key), Plant}；  
Table KPI {KID(key), ServiceID, KPI1, KPI2}.
```

Their relationship: Plant.Name = Contractor.Plant, Contractor.CID= KPI.ServiceID

Form KPI : (to input data into Table KPI) 
simplify what I want, a combo box "cbxplant" to list all plant names , when use select 1 plant in this combo box, it will lookup CID from table contractor then retrieve the value into a text box "Service ID"
I tried like this :

```
=DLookUp("[CID]","Contractor","[Plant]= '" & [Form]![KPI]![cbxplant] & "'")
```

It always show "#Name?" as result. But I can't see any mistake from my code.
Anyone could help?

P.S the combo box is using the table Plant not table Contractor to query the plant name, I don't know if it is linked to this pb? And I also want to know if FormID of 1 field is the lable name of this field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is at the reference to the combo box, the `s` is missing:

```
[Forms]![....

'String
=DLookUp("[CID]","Contractor","[Plant]= '" & [Forms]![KPI]![cbxplant] & "'")

'Double
=DLookUp("[CID]","Contractor","[Plant]= " & [Forms]![KPI]![cbxplant])
```

Here is a `DLookup()` example as well:

```
=DLookup("ColumnName", "TableName", "ColumnName = 'Criteria1'")
=DLookup("ColumnName", "TableName", "ColumnValue = 1")
```

Comment: I use your code 
=DLookUp("[CID]","Contractor","[Plant]= '" & [Forms]![KPI]![cbxplant] & "'") -- now it return empty still nok

Comment: If it returns empty then you dont have a record in your table with this condition. You can manually check that, just filter in your table the condition. Or you can use a `DCount()` if it returns `0` you dont have a record with this criteria.

Comment: I tried directly =DLookUp("[CID]","Contractor","[Plant]= 'MCD' ") it can work but with the combo box it cant

Comment: I tried another way :Private Sub Combo326_AfterUpdate()
ServiceID = DLookup("[CID]", "Contractor", "[Plant]= '" & Forms!KPI!cbxplant & "'")
End Sub ; it showed error : Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the `AfterUpdate()` event and execute the line `?DLookup("[CID]", "Contractor", "[Plant]= '" & Forms!KPI!cbxplant & "'")` in the immeadiate window and check what you get back as value

Comment: Ok then check in the immediate window with the same breakpoint if your comboBox returns a value with `?Forms!KPI!cbxplant`. If it is a combox with more as one bound column you need to refer to it with `Forms!KPI!cbxplant.Column(0)`

Comment: at the end, I resolve the problem without using Dlookup. Just choose "store value " (CID is the key of Contractor)into a field "Service ID" when I create the combo box.  But the table relationships are more complicated than the example : Contractor 1 --- more Plant, there is another Table provider. what I want, to create two combo boxes to link these 2 table, when user choose the correct provider and plant both, it can show the service ID. Anyway , thanks again for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find the root cause of this problem, the combo box of Access can't save the value of another table except the primary key of this table. 
It's not linked with Dlookup function. If I change the key of Table Plant from PID to Plant Name， it can work.